# Hawtio 2.10.0 is duplicating the URL for jolokia

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I have ActiveMQ 5.15.13 running in my localhost with jolokia without any problem:

```
# wget --user admin --password admin --header "Origin: http://localhost" --auth-no-challenge http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost
--2020-06-22 14:49:15--  http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8161... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost.2’

org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost.2                  [ <=>                                                                                                                                                               ]   2,24K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-06-22 14:49:15 (175 MB/s) - ‘org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost.2’ saved [2291]
```

Hawtio 2.10.0 looks like it's ok, but when I try to connect to ActiveMQ I receive this message:

```
This Jolokia endpoint is unreachable. Please check the connection details and try again.
```

I checked network inspector and I guess that's the problem:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8161/hawtio/proxy/http/localhost/8161/api/jolokia/
```

After some changes in the URL I noticed that there's a hardcode part of the URL:

```
http://localhost:8161/hawtio/proxy/
```

That part is always there, no matter what I do and the other part:

```
http/localhost/8161/api/jolokia/
```

Change always I change the settings, but for some reason it's became a query strings instead of be the expected URL:
http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/

That's are the options I'm using:

```
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY -Dhawtio.disableProxy=true -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect to ActiveMQ when you get the `This Jolokia endpoint is unreachable` message?

Comment: What is "network inspector"?

Comment: I created a connection into Hawtio and try to connect.
Network inspector is the "F12" from browser and Network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review a lot of "the same" procedure to install Hawtio with ActiveMQ, questions everywhere I could find it and review the documentation for both ActiveMQ and Hawtio, I could finally found some information, from 6 years ago, that suggested an "extra step" when use Hawtio with ActiveMQ which fixed my issue.

I may be wrong, but from my point of view Hawtio have a highlander bug that use the HOST URL as base, instead of the SETUP CONNECTION URL that is created, to fix that problem, just need to add the following lines into `<ACTIVEMQ PATH>/conf/jetty.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/hawtio" />
    <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio" />
    <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
</bean>
```

That's should be inside of:

```
<bean id="secHandlerCollection" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <property name="handlers">
                        <list>
                    <ref bean="rewriteHandler"/>
```